# calling render raises "Undefined method 'logger' for true class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm at a loss trying to figure out what is causing this issue. If I call any variation of `render` in my controller it raises the following:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for true:TrueClass
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/configurable.rb:113:in `logger'
```

I checked [active_support/configurable.rb:113](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/configurable.rb#L113) and I don't quite understand what it's comparing and raising for. I have other controllers that which both share the same base controller, that is not throwing this error when I `render`.

What am I not seeing here?

**EDIT**
Calling render from

```
class Device::V1::DeviceController < ApplicationController

  def status
    render json: { foo: 'bar' }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Below is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods
  before_action :authenticate!

  private

  def authenticate!
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      token == SECRET[:api_key]
    end
  end
end
```

Rails `5.1.3`

Ruby `2.3.4`

**UPDATE**
I had a method in this controller called `config`. Apparently this is a reserved namespace that conflicted with ActiveSupport

Comment: show us where you call render

Comment: @Cyzanfar updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a controller method named `config`. This is a reserved name.

Comment: You save my day!